# Request returns AccessDenied when trying to save in SQS

Tags: amazon-sqs

I have an API Gateway that publishes the request in SQS. This Gateway has SQS SendMessage policy, and this issue I am describing here does not happen when I use the Test option of the gateway.

I am using Insomnia to make requests to the server, with these headers:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
x-api-key: <My API Key>
```

Basically the configuration was done following this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@pranaysankpal/aws-api-gateway-proxy-for-sqs-simple-queue-service-5b08fe18ce50

The only difference I included the MessageGroupId on the Mapping template for deduplication:

```
Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=$input.body&MessageGroupId=$context.resourcePath
```

The response I am getting is vey weird, because it is a Http 200, with header:

```
date: Mon, 12 Apr 2021 13:05:53 GMT
content-type: application/json
content-length: 377
x-amzn-requestid: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x-amz-apigw-id: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
x-amzn-trace-id: Root=xxxxxx
```

And the body:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse
  xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-02-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access to the resource https://sqs.xxxxxxx.amazonaws.com/arn:aws:sqs:us-xxxx-x:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxx.fifo is denied.</Message>
    <Detail/>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

x's are used to hide information I am not sure are sensible.

I am not sure how to proceed, it seems to an issue while publishing in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

In my inexperience, I was not aware that API Gateway requires Deploy for most of the changes.